# How to think in React for this example: Should I store repetitive html markup in an Array and import it into a class component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making my portfolio and I have one page listing all of my archived projects. I have over 10 projects. Each project looks exactly the same just with diff info/images:

```
<div>
  <h1> Title </h1>
  <h1> Image </h1>
  <h1> Tech Stack </h1>
  <button onClick={()=> this.expandDropdown()}>Tech Stack</button>
</div>
```

The onClick button fires a function that changes the state of expand from false to true:

```
  expandDropdown =()=> {
this.setState({
  expand: !this.state.expand
})
  }
```

It's bubbling(?) so that when I click one button they all expand. My code is 245 lines which I believe is too long, so instead of making an array to mimic the number of projects I have or hardcoding an ID for each project how can I simplify my code? I feel like I should be importing the list of projects and then mapping them. I'm not sure how to move forward.

Edit: Directory:

I'm using react-router-dom so the parent is just my the switch page, which isn't handling state. I have:

```
|App.js
   |- Switch Page (router)
      | -- Best Projects(managing state)
      | -- Career Timeline
      | -- Archived Projects(managing state) <- expansion is here w/all projects
```

Both "best project" and "archived projects" are classes.

**EDIT 2: Exporting projects:**

```
    import React from "react";
import profilePhoto from "../../photos/IMG_2881.JPG";
import salAndCheong from "../../photos/salAndCheong.jpg";
import byeSal from "../../photos/goodByeSal.jpg";
import bike from "../../photos/bike.jpg";
import style from '../../styles/main.module.css'


    export default{

compo: [
    <img onMouseEnter={()=>this.imageHover()} onMouseOut={()=>this.imageHover()} className={style.noHover} src='../../photos/IMG_2881.JPG' alt="" />,
    <img onMouseEnter={()=>this.imageHover()} onMouseOut={()=>this.imageHover()} className={style.noHover} src={salAndCheong} alt="" />,
    <img onMouseEnter={()=>this.imageHover()} onMouseOut={()=>this.imageHover()} className={style.noHover} src={bike} alt="" />,
    <img onMouseEnter={()=>this.imageHover()} onMouseOut={()=>this.imageHover()} className={style.noHover} src={byeSal} alt="" />,
  ]
}e
```

Comment: There are many solutions to your problem, I cannot guess which one is best for you. Can you please post more code ? how is your component and his parent ? The expansion state should be in the child.

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea, import your list of projects and then map through them, you can extrapolate your portfolio into separate component that passes down the relevant props, then have your `onClick` event handler set up for this portfolio component so that state is scoped and not shared for every portfolio item on the containing component.

Comment: If I import my projects from another page, how do I set that page up? Should it be one large array, one large object, just a component? - What is this export called? I essentially want to avoid stashing my projects in an array between render and return. I feel like that's not convention.

Comment: Treat your portfolio list like an API, so set it up in a separate utility file, as an array containing objects (an object per portfolio item), export the array and import it into the component that will be mapping through it. This component will be the containing component and in your `map` method you will render out the portfolio component and pass down the portfolio item (the `map` method instance) as `props`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense! It's working when I did export default, see above. The images aren't exporting. But I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Would probably be better just to export those imported image variables rather than the a whole element for each index. Your syntax doesn't look quite right there as well, if you can set up a React code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/new) I can check it out, then we can continue this over in the JS chat. Otherwise, I'm sure you'll figure it out, you're definitely on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Data :** Add your portfolio data into an array and export it, treat it like an api
2. **Parent Component :** Import your portfolio data in a container parent component and map through it, passing down the props
3. **Child Component :** Extrapolate your portfolios into a separate presentational component that will receive props
4. **Scope :** Render props within this presentational component and handle any other event handlers to scope it (you can treat state this way too)

**Portfolio API**

```
// portfolios-data.js
import image0 from "../src/assets/images/image0.jpg";
import image1 from "../src/assets/images/image1.jpg";
import image2 from "../src/assets/images/image2.jpg";
import image3 from "../src/assets/images/image3.jpg";

export const portfoliosData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'portfolio 0',
    image: image0,
    techStack: 'Foo, Bar, Baz',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'portfolio 1',
    image: image1,
    techStack: 'Foo, Bar, Baz',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'portfolio 2',
    image: image2,
    techStack: 'Foo, Bar, Baz',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'portfolio 3',
    image: image3,
    techStack: 'Foo, Bar, Baz',
  },
]
```

**Projects containing component**

```
// Projects.js container component
import React from "react";
// Utils
import { portfoliosData } from "../../utils/portfolios-data"; // ./src/utils/
// Components
import Protfolio from "../presentational/Protfolio"; // ./src/components/presentational

export default function Projects() {

  return (
    <div className="projects">
      <h2>Projects</h2>
      <ul className="portfolioList">
        {portfoliosData.map(portfolio => {
          <li key={portfolio.id}><Protfolio props={portfolio} /></li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Portfolio child component**

```
// Portfolio.js presentational component
import React from "react";

export default function Portfolio(props) {

  const { 
    title,    // string
    image,    // string (filepath)
    techStack // string
  } = props;

  // scoped event handlers
  const expandDropdown = () => {
    /* ... */
  }

  // keep html semantic, only h1 per page, keep h2s at a minimum
  return (
    <div className="portfolio">
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <img src={image} alt={title} />
      <h4>{techStack}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => expandDropdown()}>Tech Stack</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```